# Lightning Web Component Combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

i'm developing lightning web component and i want to fill or populate my combobox from result of apex method so how i can in the html file get the result from JavaScript file and put them in the combobox.

Template:

```
 <lightning-combobox
            name="Role"
            label="Role Name"
            value={value}
            placeholder=""
            options={rolesList.data.values}
            onchange={handleChange} >
        </lightning-combobox>
```

javascript file:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';

import getRoles from '@salesforce/apex/LeaveSettingsController.getRoles';

@wire(getRoles)
    rolesList;
```

Comment: What have tried so far? can you please add your code to the question

Comment: @RedDevil i post my code in an answer

Comment: Added answer to your question

Comment: @sallyyamak What does `LeaveSettingsController.getRoles` return, a `List<String>`?

Comment: yes it returns a list<String>

Comment: Check my approach

Answer (score 12):

Though I am late in answering this question, but here is the other approach to populate combo box values.

**Controller**

Here retrieve UserRole records based on SOQL query and no data transformation in this class

```
public with sharing class UserRoleController {

    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<UserRole> getUserRoles(){
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole];
    }
}
```

**js Controller class**

In this class, inside `wiredUserRoles()` method, perform data transformation for value and label.

Use, `roleOptions()` getter property to return the array.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement , wire, track} from 'lwc';

//import method which should be used from Controller
import getUserRoles from '@salesforce/apex/UserRoleController.getUserRoles';

let i=0;
export default class DisplayUserRole extends LightningElement {

    @track items = []; //this will hold key, value pair
    @track value = ''; //initialize combo box value

    @track chosenValue = '';

    @wire(getUserRoles)
    wiredUserRoles({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {

            //create array with elements which has been retrieved controller
            //here value will be Id and label of combobox will be Name
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)  {
                this.items = [...this.items ,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name} ];                                   
            }                
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        }
    }

    //gettter to return items which is mapped with options attribute
    get roleOptions() {
        return this.items;
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        // Get the string of the "value" attribute on the selected option
        const selectedOption = event.detail.value;
        console.log('selected value=' + selectedOption);
        this.chosenValue = selectedOption;
    }

    //this value will be shown as selected value of combobox item
    get selectedValue(){
        return this.chosenValue;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Display User Role" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <lightning-combobox
            name="Role"
            label="Role Name"
            placeholder="Choose Role"
            value={value}
            onchange={handleChange}
            options={roleOptions}>
        </lightning-combobox>
        <p></p>
        Selected Value:
        <lightning-formatted-text title="Chosen Key" value={selectedValue}></lightning-formatted-text>
    </lightning-card>

</template>
```

**Output**

[image: Display User Role]

After selection, display the value.

[image: Selected value]

Comment: You could also use a nifty Javascript array function "map".      if (data) { this.roleOptions = data.map(function (userRole){ return {label:userRole.Name, value:userRole.Id} });

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a javascript property on the template like below

```
options={rolesOptions}
```

and in the javascript file

create a getter function for it

```
get rolesOptions() {
        return this.rolesList.data.values;
    }
```

I havent tested this solution but should work theoretically based on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) documentation

Comment: This will work only if the combobox (since it will request the getter) is surrounded with `<template if:true={rolesList.data}>`. And taking a second look at the question, it should work even if no getter function were created but @sally yamak surrounded the combobox with the condition render anyways.

Comment: Thank you RedDevil, tsalb i will try this....

Comment: I try it and it's also not working the combobox is empty

Comment: Can you console log the output of roleslist to the question

Comment: Can you also check if your aura enabled method cacheable is set to true

Comment: Hello RedDevil , yes my method is cacheable true... but i resolve my issue and now it works. in Lightning Web Component to fill a Combobox you need a pair of attributes Label and Value.For this reason i create a wrapper in my Apex Class with two attributes one for label and one for Value to save the result come from getRoles() method into this wrapper it's an efficient method and it works like a magic

Comment: Your wrapper should work without @AuraEnabled and getter setter.

Answer (score 2):

Apex code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getValues() {
    SummaryList = new List<Summary>();
    List<Object> ConfigListGrupos = new List<Object>();

    ConfigListGrupos = [SELECT (Filed 1), DCABM_fld_valor__c 
            FROM .....];

    for(Object a : ConfigListGrupos) {
        SummaryList.add(new Summary(a.(Filed 1), a.DCABM_fld_valor__c));               
    }

    String jSONSummaryList = JSON.serialize(SummaryList);
    return jSONSummaryList;
}

public class Summary {
    public String value {get;set;}
    public String label {get;set;}

    public Summary(String param1, String param2) {
        value = param1;
        label = param2;
    }
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getValues from '@salesforce/apex/(Your Class).getValues';

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {
@track options;

@wire(getValues)
wiredValues({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.options = JSON.parse(data);
    } else if (error) {
        window.console.log('Error in wiredValues');
        window.console.log(error);
    }
}
}
```

HTML code:

```
<template>
  <lightning-combobox
     name="type"
     label="Type values"
     placeholder="Select values"
     options={options}
     data-field="userType"
     required>
  </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apex Class:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<OptionWrapper> getRoles(){
       List<OptionWrapper> roleNameList = new List<OptionWrapper>();
       for(userRole role :[SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole]){
         roleNameList.add(new OptionWrapper(role.Name, role.Name));
       }
       System.debug(roleNameList);
       return roleNameList;
    }

    public class OptionWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String value {get; set;}

        public OptionWrapper(String label, String value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

Template:

```
  <lightning-combobox
                name="Role"
                label="Role Name"
                value={value}
                placeholder=""
                options={rolesOptions}
                onchange={handleChange} >
            </lightning-combobox>
```

Js File:

```
@track value = 'CEO';
@wire(getRoles)
    rolesList; 

    get rolesOptions() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('>>>>'+JSON.stringify(this.rolesList.data));
        return this.rolesList.data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like previous answers got it right, but didn't highlight what was wrong with the initial code. The main caveat here is what you're passing to `options` attribute of the `<lightning-combobox/>`: `rolesList.data.values`. It's most likely that your controller method is returning a `List<String>`, which is interpreted as an array of strings on the receiving end. So your `roleList.data` will most likely contain an array of strings, which is not a suitable input for lightning-combobox's options.

As per the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example)'s JS example, it accepts an array of objects that have `label` and `value` keys. Now, it's not very convenient to generate that in Apex, rather I would make this array in the component's JS file's `@wire`-provisioned function. The following example provides a more concise version of some of the earlier answers.

```
@wire(getUserRoles) getUserRoles({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.rolesList = data.map(role => ({ label: role, value: role }));
    } else {
        console.debug(error);
    }
};
```

And then use `rolesList` variable in the template:

```
   <lightning-combobox
        name="Role"
        label="Role Name"
        value={value}
        placeholder=""
        options={rolesList}
        onchange={handleChange} >
    </lightning-combobox>
```